# Finding limit of $\frac{a_n^3+5n}{a_n^2+n}$ for $(a_n)$ bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Suppose that the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded. Prove that the sequence $(c_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ defined by
>   $$
> c_n = \frac{a_n^3+5n}{a_n^2+n}
> $$
>   is convergent and find its limit.

Would appreciate advice as to how to approach this question.

Comment: Hint:  divide numerator and denominator by $n$.

Comment: If you plant to participate in the Math.SE community, you may be interested in [using MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to include $\LaTeX$ markup for mathematical expressions in your posts.  This is preferrable to posting images.

Comment: Would that use the idea that since $An^3$ has an upper bound, $An^3/n$ tends to 0?

Comment: @Hamza yes, indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINTS**

1. Since $a_n$ is bounded, what are $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n^3}{n} \text{ and } \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n^2}{n}?$$
2. Note that $$\frac{a_n^3+5n}{a_n^2+n} = \frac{5 + a_n^3/n}{1 + a_n^2/n}.$$